# Nginx as proxy server for sockio.io websocket not working on remote

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io-1.0

On my developing macchine I have nginx as proxy server for websocket with this configuration:

```
server {
  listen       80;

  location /socket.io {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://trunk.alban:81;
    client_max_body_size 500M;

  }
}
```

When I access from the same macchine via firefox the websockets connects correctly and start exchanging messages:

```
[root@localhost nodejs]# node websocket.js 

2014-12-04 10:27:16 ==> Listening on port: 3001
2014-12-04 10:27:16 ==> Auth token: alyt4qxs9k9k95a7q1if6r3a8b7yzaor
2014-12-04 10:27:29 ==> Client authorized: alyt4qxs9k9k95a7q1if6r3a8b7yzaor == alyt4qxs9k9k95a7q1if6r3a8b7yzaor
2014-12-04 10:27:29 ==> IP: [127.0.0.1], URL:[http://trunk.alban], Agent: [Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0] 
2014-12-04 10:27:35 ==> Broadcasting clients: amend-view-status_13 {}
```

But When I accesss from another macchine, it connects but it does not sending/receiving any message, just loops in switching protocols, connecting and disconneting:

```
2014-12-04 10:32:23 ==> Client authorized: alyt4qxs9k9k95a7q1if6r3a8b7yzaor == alyt4qxs9k9k95a7q1if6r3a8b7yzaor
2014-12-04 10:32:23 ==> IP: [127.0.0.1], URL:[http://192.168.57.130], Agent: [Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0] 
2014-12-04 10:32:43 ==> Client Disconnected
2014-12-04 10:32:44 ==> Client authorized: alyt4qxs9k9k95a7q1if6r3a8b7yzaor == alyt4qxs9k9k95a7q1if6r3a8b7yzaor
2014-12-04 10:32:44 ==> IP: [127.0.0.1], URL:[http://192.168.57.130], Agent: [Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0] 
2014-12-04 10:33:04 ==> Client Disconnected
2014-12-04 10:33:06 ==> Client authorized: alyt4qxs9k9k95a7q1if6r3a8b7yzaor == alyt4qxs9k9k95a7q1if6r3a8b7yzaor
2014-12-04 10:33:06 ==> IP: [127.0.0.1], URL:[http://192.168.57.130], Agent: [Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0]
```

I have nginx 1.6.2 installed and socket.io 1.2.1.

I have disable all possible firewalls.

**NOTE:** If I remove nginx as proxy server, just by poiting to the socket.io server directly it works all fine in any macchine.

**NOTE2**: forcing using polling it works with no problems. Seems to be a problem with nginx/ws protocol...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the problem: On the client side I had set the transports option:

```
this.socket = io.connect(this.adress, {query: 'token='+this.token /* , resource: 'ws/socket.io' */, transports:['websocket', 'polling']});
```

By removing it:

```
this.socket = io.connect(this.adress, {query: 'token='+this.token});
```

IT WORKS, from any remote connection!!! I cannot explain why but it works.

Hope this helps for any other user